# Angular.js: Wrapping elements in a nested transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This seems like such a simple thing, but I am just not able to wrap my head around how to do it.

Here is what I want:

```
<my-buttons>
  <my-button ng-click="doOneThing()">abc</my-button>
  <my-button ng-click="doAnotherThing()">def</my-button>
</my-buttons>
```

That turns into something like this:

```
<ul class="u">
  <li class="l"><button ng-click="doOneThing()">abc</button></li>
  <li class="l"><button ng-click="doAnotherThing()">def</button></li>
</ul>
```

Notice how the `ng-click` is on the `button`, inside a wrapping `li`. However, the normal transclusion will place the `ng-click` on the `li`.

My best try is on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WTv7k/1/ There I have replaced the ng-click with a class, so it is easy to see when it works and not.

Any ideas of how to get this done? If it is really easy, maybe the tabs/pane example on the frontpage could be expanded to include a wrapper around the panes, while still keeping the attributes.

Comment: pretty simple in my mind... root of template that replaces the element is `<li>` and  attributes of `<my-button>` get transfered to root element of template

Comment: for a more dynamic template that needs to access attributes in order to create template look at using `$complile` and setting element html yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With *replace:true* the replacement process migrates all of the attributes / classes from the old element (*<my-button ...>*) to the new one (the root element in the template, *<li ...>* ). Transclude moves the content of the old element to the specified (ng-transclude) element. I'm not sure if there's a simple way to change which element in the template that will receive the migrated attributes.

To achieve what you want you could probably do some dom manipulation in a custom compile function in the my-button directive. However, I think it'd be a better idea to create a new isolate scope in the my-button directive:

```xml
<my-buttons>
  <my-button click-fn="doOneThing()">abc</my-button>
  <my-button click-fn="doAnotherThing()">def</my-button>
</my-buttons>
```

(notice I've changed ng-click to click-fn)

```js
module.directive('myButtons', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    transclude:true,
    replace:true,
    template:'<ul class="u" ng-transclude></ul>'
  }
});

module.directive('myButton', function () {
  return {
    scope:{clickFn:'&'},
    restrict:'E',
    transclude:true,
    replace:true,
    template:'<li class="l"><button ng-click="clickFn()" ng-transclude></button></li>'
  }
});
```

I've also made a [working version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UWEsN/).

To understand how the isolate scope works (*scope:{clickFn:'&'}*) I recommend you read the  [angular guide on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: Does the clickFn not receive the new isolated scope tho?

Comment: No, like I said - notice `scope:{clickFn:'&'}`. From the angular guide: & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope.

Comment: It's basically the same as doing the following in the 'myButton'-controller:

`var fn = $parse($attrs.clickFn);// converts an angular expression into a function, e.g "doOneThing()"`

`$scope.clickFn = function(){ fn($scope.$parent);} //execute the function in the contex of the parent scope`